# ¿Cómo corresponder VARIOS elementos de una LISTA con UN elemento de otra en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, matplotlib

Apenas llevo un par de meses programando y tengo que hacer esta operación.

En concreto lo que necesito es relacionar una lista de muchos datos como en mi caso es 'array', a otra lista como es 'months':

```
array = ['309', '307', '303', '296', '322', '340', '321', '314', '327', '315', '316', '333', '296', '286', '289', '290', '316', '317', '333', '348', '398', '396', '404', '424', '402', '357', '320', '315', '321', '328', '312', '293', '302', '296', '286', '281', '281', '  0', '312', '326', '332', '293', '242', '259', '268', '316', '296', '303', '280', '308', '314', '298', '307', '303', '300', '284', '289', '337', '308', '300', '288', '333', '321', '373', '301', '272', '288', '322', '318', '314', '321', '297', '299', '306', '312', '325', '334', '390', '339', '317', '343', '336', '357', '366', '383', '379', '355', '342', '369', '362', '359', '360', '380', '388', '393', '362', '347', '335', '322', '334', '313', '309', '303', '304', '326', '354', '364', '360', '343', '335', '343', '366', '318', '347', '326', '327', '329', '334', '347', '364', '346', '338', '337', '325', '304', '285', '298', '310', '316', '311', '321', '323', '360', '351', '337', '345', '372', '367', '356', '331', '308', '323', '327', '312', '300', '296', '305', '323', '338', '328', '319', '315', '315', '313', '316', '314', '312', '354', '317', '323', '324', '352', '360', '342', '333', '348', '335', '320', '321', '326', '327', '323', '303', '318', '308', '307', '302', '293', '304', '322', '302', '307', '304', '302', '287', '290', '306', '299', '297', '284', '289', '287', '316', '292', '291', '307', '300', '318', '302', '309', '320', '296', '293', '291', '287', '293', '287', '296', '293', '297', '287', '296', '296', '290', '287', '290', '290', '302', '298', '301', '297', '302', '290', '297', '288', '288', '299', '319', '311', '300', '302', '305', '294', '293', '288', '288', '289', '291', '286', '282', '280', '287', '279', '294', '345', '344', '292', '317', '296', '287', '288', '285', '291', '300', '298', '288', '288', '287', '275', '282', '288', '270', '272', '283', '284', '284', '295', '290', '279', '290', '287', '276', '289', '286', '295', '301', '287', '332', '305', '304', '275', '263', '266', '256', '257', '269', '258', '257', '273', '291', '277', '272', '280', '266', '269', '256', '282', '274', '308', '295', '288', '331', '290', '295', '283', '288', '285', '267', '274', '279', '300', '290', '293', '308', '285', '288', '279', '270', '281', '297', '296', '275', '255', '242', '239', '242', '269', '275', '278', '286', '276', '269', '283', '290', '317', '286', '287', '282', '273', '289', '322', '352', '268', '290', '311', '277', '256', '246', '255', '252', '265', '269', '265', '278', '272', '273', '302', '287', '284', '316', '318', '310', '280', '288', '293', '291']

months=['January 2020', 'February 2020', 'March 2020', 'April 2020', 'May 2020', 'June 2020', 'July 2020', 'August 2020', 'September 2020', 'October 2020', 'November 2020', 'December 2020']
```

En total en 'array' hay 364 valores, correspondientes a cada día del año (en concreto desde el 01-01-2020 hasta el 29-12-2020), por lo que la idea sería que, contando que el primer valor del 'array' corresponde al 01-01-2020 y el último valor al 29-12-2020, me identificase cada 31 o 30 valores (en el caso de febrero de 2020 y diciembre, 29 valores) al correspondiente mes del año que equivalen.

Lo que quiero es finalmente representarlo gráficamente (months eje x, array eje y), con alguna librería tipo matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(months, array)
plt.ylabel('Ozone Madrid')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.show()
```

Actualmente no me vale escribirlo así ya que con estos comandos necesito que las listas que meto dentro de  'plt.plot()' sean del mismo número de elementos, por ello necesito hacer este paso (si hay alguna otra vía más fácil también agradezco la explicación)

No sé si existirá algún comando o hay que hacer un código para lograr lo que quiero, pero les agradeceré cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la función `pd.date_range()` de la librería `Pandas` que te hace esto de forma sencilla.

Simplemente a `pd.date_range(<fecha_inicio>, <fecha_fin>)` ponemos una fecha de inicio y otra de fin. Aquí el código de tu ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = ['309', '307', '303', '296', '322', '340', '321', '314', '327', '315', '316', '333', '296', '286', '289', '290', '316', '317', '333', '348', '398', '396', '404', '424', '402', '357', '320', '315', '321', '328', '312', '293', '302', '296', '286', '281', '281', '  0', '312', '326', '332', '293', '242', '259', '268', '316', '296', '303', '280', '308', '314', '298', '307', '303', '300', '284', '289', '337', '308', '300', '288', '333', '321', '373', '301', '272', '288', '322', '318', '314', '321', '297', '299', '306', '312', '325', '334', '390', '339', '317', '343', '336', '357', '366', '383', '379', '355', '342', '369', '362', '359', '360', '380', '388', '393', '362', '347', '335', '322', '334', '313', '309', '303', '304', '326', '354', '364', '360', '343', '335', '343', '366', '318', '347', '326', '327', '329', '334', '347', '364', '346', '338', '337', '325', '304', '285', '298', '310', '316', '311', '321', '323', '360', '351', '337', '345', '372', '367', '356', '331', '308', '323', '327', '312', '300', '296', '305', '323', '338', '328', '319', '315', '315', '313', '316', '314', '312', '354', '317', '323', '324', '352', '360', '342', '333', '348', '335', '320', '321', '326', '327', '323', '303', '318', '308', '307', '302', '293', '304', '322', '302', '307', '304', '302', '287', '290', '306', '299', '297', '284', '289', '287', '316', '292', '291', '307', '300', '318', '302', '309', '320', '296', '293', '291', '287', '293', '287', '296', '293', '297', '287', '296', '296', '290', '287', '290', '290', '302', '298', '301', '297', '302', '290', '297', '288', '288', '299', '319', '311', '300', '302', '305', '294', '293', '288', '288', '289', '291', '286', '282', '280', '287', '279', '294', '345', '344', '292', '317', '296', '287', '288', '285', '291', '300', '298', '288', '288', '287', '275', '282', '288', '270', '272', '283', '284', '284', '295', '290', '279', '290', '287', '276', '289', '286', '295', '301', '287', '332', '305', '304', '275', '263', '266', '256', '257', '269', '258', '257', '273', '291', '277', '272', '280', '266', '269', '256', '282', '274', '308', '295', '288', '331', '290', '295', '283', '288', '285', '267', '274', '279', '300', '290', '293', '308', '285', '288', '279', '270', '281', '297', '296', '275', '255', '242', '239', '242', '269', '275', '278', '286', '276', '269', '283', '290', '317', '286', '287', '282', '273', '289', '322', '352', '268', '290', '311', '277', '256', '246', '255', '252', '265', '269', '265', '278', '272', '273', '302', '287', '284', '316', '318', '310', '280', '288', '293', '291']

#Los número están en formato string, por lo que los convertimos a enteros
array = [int(n) for n in array]

#Nos creamos un rango de fechas
months = pd.date_range("01-01-2020", "31-12-2020")


plt.plot(months, array)
plt.ylabel('Ozone Madrid')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Véase como también he convertido todos los números a enteros para que `matplotlib` pueda representarlo perfectamente.